Setting all values before index location to np.NaN
Lets say we have an array like below:
a = np.array(np.arange(15)).reshape(3,-1)


array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

and a list which has the locations, and we want to set everything before these to np.NaN
l = [0,2,1]

The end result would be:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [nan, nan,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [nan, 11., 12., 13., 14.]])

Is there a way to do this within numpy? The only solution I can think of without iterating is to create an dummy array with index locations, but was wondering if there was a better way that I was missing. Thank you.
Current solution:
s = a.shape
a = a.astype(float)
a[np.where((np.array([[*np.arange(s[-1])]]*s[0]) < np.array(l)[:,None]))] = np.NaN


Using broadcasting :
a = a.astype("float")

m = np.arange(a.shape[1]) < np.array(l)[:, None]

a[m] = np.nan

Output :
>>> a
# array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
#        [nan, nan,  7.,  8.,  9.],
#        [nan, 11., 12., 13., 14.]])

Intermediates :
>>> np.arange(a.shape[1])
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> np.array(l)[:, None]
# array([[0],
#        [2],
#        [1]])

>>> m
# array([[False, False, False, False, False],
#        [ True,  True, False, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False, False, False]])

An alternative (suggested by @mozway) that avoids casting and puts nan where it should :
out = np.where(
    np.arange(a.shape[1]) >= np.array(l)[:, None], a, np.nan
)


You were faster ;)

Haha, for once ;)

An alternative: out = np.where(np.arange(a.shape[1]) >= np.array(l)[:, None], a, np.nan)

Cool. I've integrated to the answer, thanks mozway ;)
